# Data normalization in Excel

Tags: excel, normalization, excel-2016

I want to perform normalization in Excel between 0 and 1 for the following sample data in column A. I tried it with the following formula but the results are completely different from 0 and 1. Any help?

```
=(A1-MIN($A$1:$A$57))/(MAX($A$1:$A$57)-MIN($A$1:$A$57))


482991710
1059841418
482991711
482991711
482991735
482993183
482994631
482996079
482997527
482998975
483000423
483001871
483003319
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
483004767
483006215
483007663
483009111
483010559
483012007
483013455
483014903
483016351
483017799
483019247
483020695
483022143
483023591
483025039
483026487
483027935
483029383
483030831
483032279
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
1059841419
483033727
483035175
483036623
1059841419
1059841419
```

Comment: `the results are completely different from 0 and 1.` ... no they're not, the results are all in between 0 and 1, which is what you want, if I read your question correctly.

Comment: `1.73355E-09, 
1.73355E-09, 
4.33388E-08, ` for example these are the results i got on rows 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: The smallest value is `482991710`, and the values on rows 3, 4, and 5 are very close to this.  Hence, after your normalization, these three rows are very close to zero.  Maybe you can change your formula if you want a different distribution?

Comment: Change format to `Number`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manually change format to number you can use this:

```
=TEXT((A1-MIN($A$1:$A$57))/(MAX($A$1:$A$57)-MIN($A$1:$A$57)),0)*1
```

--EDIT--

You can also try `ROUND` if the formula above still gives you scientific format:

```
=ROUND((A1-MIN($A$1:$A$57))/(MAX($A$1:$A$57)-MIN($A$1:$A$57)),0)
```

Comment: I still am getting some numbers in scientific notation. But if i have 300,000 rows and it was to apply for the entire column

Comment: Please take a look at edit, worked for me as I created dummy data for 300,000 rows.